# Load images from folder and use them as sprites in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have an idea about a game, where you need to catch flags. In the game I want to give the user the opportunity to use his own images. I was thinking the user could input a folder directory and I would access the directory and use the images stored there. Is this possible in C#? If so, how could I do it?

For example, the user would input "C:\Users\Bob\Documents\GameImages" and I would use the images stored there to create the falling flags.

Comment: You'd probably get a better answer at answers.unity3d.com

Comment: Would Resources.load() be able to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

either of those should work on standalone
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html